# IndexError when trying to convert a txt file into JSON format

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use regular expressions to convert a `.txt` file into `json`.

This is the text file's format:
(a bunch of lines in each line there's a word and it's meaning seperated by `,`

```
hello, Hallo
love, Liebe
dog, Hund
...
```

This is the desired output:

```
[
  {
    "wordId": 1,
    "englishWord": "hello",
    "germanWord": "Hallo"
  },
  {
    "wordId": 2,
    "englishWord": "love",
    "germanWord": "Liebe"
  },
  {
    "wordId": 3,
    "englishWord": "dog",
    "germanWord": "Hund"
  }
]
```

**Q:** What is the pattern I should use to get that outcome? and How can I make this happen using python?

**UPDATE**
I am using this suggested script:

```
import json

with open('words.txt', 'r') as f_in, \
    open('converted.json', 'w') as f_out:
data = [
    {"wordId": i, "englishWord": line.split(',')[0].strip(), "germanWord": line.split(',')[1].strip()} for i, line in
    enumerate(f_in, 1)]
f_out.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

But the output `.json` file is completely empty and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/vox/Pycharm/converterjson/script.py", line 7, in <module>
enumerate(f_in, 1)]
File "C:/Users/vox/Pycharm/converterjson/script.py", line 6, in <listcomp>
{"wordId": i, "englishWord": line.split(',')[0].strip(), "germanWord": line.split(',')[1].strip()} for i, line in
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: This is too broad. You need to have a go yourself and ask specific questions when you run into problems. (Note, I can't see any reason to use regex here.)

Comment: You could try using the [JSON module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html).

Comment: it's a long list that's best be automated, and I never used python and/or regex

Comment: and how python and regex would know whether it's `"germanWord"` or `"norseWord"` ???

Comment: Your input suggests a .csv file not a .txt file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex isn't necessary, you can use Python's `json` module.

If `file.txt` contains:

```
hello, Hallo
love, Liebe
dog, Hund
```

Then this script:

```
import json

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f_in, \
    open('file.json', 'w') as f_out:

    data = [{"wordId":i, "englishWord": line.split(',')[0].strip(), "germanWord": line.split(',')[1].strip()} for i, line in enumerate(f_in, 1)]
    f_out.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Produces `file.json`:

```
[
    {
        "wordId": 1,
        "englishWord": "hello",
        "germanWord": "Hallo"
    },
    {
        "wordId": 2,
        "englishWord": "love",
        "germanWord": "Liebe"
    },
    {
        "wordId": 3,
        "englishWord": "dog",
        "germanWord": "Hund"
    }
]
```

---

EDIT: If your input file has empty lines, this code will check for it:

```
import json

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f_in, \
    open('file.json', 'w') as f_out:

    cnt = 1
    data  = []
    for line in f_in:
        line = line.split(',')
        if len(line) != 2:
            continue
        d = {"wordId":cnt, "englishWord": line[0].strip(), "germanWord": line[1].strip()}
        data.append(d)
        cnt +=1

    f_out.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Comment: please check the update I made, something went wrong

Comment: try to refresh !

Comment: @ThorvaldÓlavsenV. Probably your input file has empty lines. Check my update.

Comment: thank you for your contribution, that did the trick and saved me a tremendous amount of time! much appreciated